# PHP Include with class?

Tags: php, class, include

Is it wrong to include the pages like this :

/index.php

```
<?php
require ('class/incEngine.php');
$inc = new includeEngine;

include($inc->_DIR_()); //IF EMPTY q= load default page if isset q=bla load bla.php

include($inc->_DIR_('contact')); // Load contact.php
?>
```

/class/IncEngine.php

```
<?php
class includeEngine{
    public $ext = '.php'; //Extension
    public $page = 'page/'; // root of inc PAGE
    public $dirof;

    function _DIR_($data = false){
        if($data == false){ //if i not set param.. $data 
            if(isset($_GET['q'])){ // if isset 'q=blablal'
                $get = $_GET['q']; // get q
                $this->dirof = $this->page."$get".$this->ext; // create dir and data is:
            } else { // if i not set q= or if q is empty then data will be ->
                $this->dirof = $this->page.'home'.$this->ext; //Default page
            }
        } else { // if isset data or q=bla
            $this->dirof = $this->page."$data".$this->ext; // make path 
        }
        if(file_exists($this->dirof)){ //check if file exsits in /page/ directory
            $return = $this->dirof; // if exists then return
        } else { // if file is not exists then redirect to 404
            Header('Location: /404.php');
        }

        return $return;
    }
}
?>
```

my tree:

---

```
class/

 1. incEngine.php

page/
 1. about.php
 2. contact.php

404.php
index.php
```

---

If this way is wrong , please explain me why is wrong ?
Can you put a link examples, How to include page with class.
Thanks.

Comment: "wrong" from what perspective? Does it work? If it does not - it's wrong.

Comment: is work perfect, but... How much is differences between classic include like this
include 'folder/'.$_GET['q']; fi(q) ..... 

and this up code ? make slow loading ?

Comment: Performance is not what you should care about. Performance optimisation **is** a rocket science. So don't worry and just learn how to write cleaner/more maintainable code yet.

Comment: Thanks, i will try to be better :D